# SSH stuck to client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0

Tags: ssh, vagrant, private-key, macos-high-sierra, tunneling

I am trying to connect to a vagrant machine on my mac (I'm using Mac OS High Sierra).
I'm using a private key to connect to it but I get stuck on this line:

```
client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

I use the following command line:

```
ssh -v -N  -L localhost:5432:192.168.33.10:5432 -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -i /Users/MacUser/Desktop/Vagrant_Project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -p 22 vagrant@192.168.33.10
```

and this is the result:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.10 [192.168.33.10] port 22.
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/MacUser/Desktop/Vagrant_Project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/MacUser/Desktop/Vagrant_Project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.33.10:22 as 'vagrant'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Ju/ngomtpiyMPtrgFsK+ttKbFUR9BwW3CyDFjo5KITc
debug1: Host '192.168.33.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/MacUser/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/MacUser/Desktop/Vagrant_Project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.33.10 ([192.168.33.10]:22).
debug1: Local connections to localhost:5432 forwarded to remote address 192.168.33.10:5432
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5432.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5432.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

Could someone give me a hint to get rid of this problem? I get stuck to this point, forever.
I think the problem should be between Vagrant and Mac Os. The same vagrant virtual machine works under a Windows environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with ProxyJump directive while connecting through bastion host to an instance. The process was timing out after the same line. Turned out there was a problem with Firewall dropping connection from bastion host.

As far as I can see your connection to **192.168.33.10** succeeds and hangs after opening listening port **5423** on localhost. So you either have a firewall blocking connections to localhost on port **5423** or a firewall on **192.168.33.10** blocking port **5423**.

To solve this you have to test these ports manually with **telnet\nmap** utilities
The syntax is as follows:

```
telnet localhost 5423
```

or

```
nmap -p 5423 192.168.33.10
```

If port is open you will see the following message

> Escape character is '^]'.

If port is closed by firewall telnet will hang with the following message

> Trying 172.18.0.47...

If port is closed by fireawll nmap will show you that its filtered

> PORT   STATE    SERVICE
>
> 80/tcp filtered http

If port is open via firewall but there's no application listening on this port you will get a message

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

After that you need to open those ports. On linux machines simply issue following command

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5423 --syn -j ACCEPT && service iptables save
```

On MacOS you need to modify this file **/etc/pf.conf** (found via this [article](https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/))